# GeoPandas: How to obtain bounding boxes for every geometry in a geodataframe

Tags: geospatial, shapely, geopandas

I am using GeoPandas in python and have a valid GeoDataframe of polygons.

```
0         POLYGON Z ((68.70999999999999 623.1 0, 35.71 6...
1         POLYGON Z ((221.33 645.02 0, 185.7 640.33 0, 1...
2         POLYGON Z ((150.3 650 0, 160.9 650 0, 150.58 6...
```

I want to obtain a new dataframe that has the bounding box coordinates for each row in the dataframe.

Now I am getting some odd behavior for GeoPandas.

Say I name the GeoDataFrame `gdf`, then using the code:

```
gdf.bounds
```

I get the corresponding error. I have no clue what this error is supposed to mean, since I did not pass any values into the `bounds` method--they were passed implicitly.

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 110042), indices imply (4, 110042)
```

When I try:
    `gdf.geometry.bounds`
I get the same `ValueError...`

However, when I do it this way, I get a valid answer:

```
gdf.head(10).bounds
```

I get

```
    minx    miny    maxx    maxy
0   0.00    618.15  68.71   650.00
1   169.56  640.33  221.33  650.00
2   150.30  648.64  160.90  650.00
```

So `gdf` and `gdf.head()` are not any different, yet one gives me an error and one does not. Does anyone know the correct way to get the bounding boxes corresponding to each row.

Comment: gdf.bounds works fine for me (in 2D)... Did you try to change your dataset ?

Comment: I figured out the problem. So basically when the `bounds` method encountered an empty polygon, that is a polygon win wkt "POLYGON EMPTY" then it would crash with this error. Now I think that the POLYGON EMPTY is a valid wkt string, but it was giving me this ValueError. So after I filtered out these empty polygons, then it worked as expected.

Comment: @krishnab would you mind writing your above comment as an answer to this question, so that it no longer shows up as "unanswered"? Thanks!

Comment: @dericke thanks for the tip. Yeah, I can actually fill in the details in an answer. No problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try the following

```
# remove empty geometry
valid_geom = gdf[gdf.geometry.map(lambda z: True if not z.is_empty else False)]
# get the bounds of each geometry
valid_geom.geometry.map(lambda z: z.exterior.xy)

# or in one line
gdf[gdf.geometry.map(lambda z: True if not z.is_empty else False)].geometry.map(lambda z: z.exterior.xy)
```

This would result in the following output. you get (minx, miny, maxx, maxy) as a list.

```
0     ([346494.47052450513, 346512.1633455531, 34642...
1     ([347156.6195963654, 347140.5694171803, 347106...
2     ([347374.2493280142, 347343.280266067, 347331....
3     ([347752.9399173185, 347732.0804000348, 347699...
4     ([352462.7065634858, 352421.82634455897, 35239...
5     ([352398.84073305037, 352366.62657852937, 3523...
6     ([351619.2911484046, 351581.3489685701, 351559...
7     ([349298.04394918215, 349284.4299869118, 34926...
8     ([349402.6562116009, 349390.3714050767, 349364...
9     ([347447.35067824554, 347427.2888365253, 34740...
10    ([351038.9227137904, 351023.75894022046, 35101...
11    ([352360.8991716495, 352311.8060843693, 352289...
12    ([348053.8637179602, 348014.5578245763, 347995...
13    ([350854.3664365387, 350802.39711500367, 35075...
14    ([350661.291738528, 350539.01532645256, 350497...
15    ([349634.9936554617, 349617.43041924713, 34959...
16    ([346588.703008323, 346576.2541223159, 346560....
17    ([347323.7364982413, 347311.6537559405, 347289...
18    ([347592.9326738138, 347588.24603437353, 34757...
19    ([347871.4965194545, 347852.9032783319, 347846...
20    ([349503.7927385038, 349484.6946827946, 349482...
21    ([349917.505834857, 349907.19522809517, 349885...
22    ([350254.82670837734, 350243.1101097837, 35024...
dtype: object
```